# Exibir uma `section` após 2 minutos do clique no botão play do vídeo no Youtube

Tags: javascript, html5

Em um vídeo upado no Vimeo eu aprendi como se faz, agora no **Youtube** eu não estou conseguindo.

A minha situação é, tenho uma `div` onde dentro dela tenho um `iframe` com o vídeo incorporado. O que eu preciso é pegar o evento do click no play do vídeo, para que com isso eu crie uma condição que após dois minutos eu exiba uma `section`.

Eu tentei usando a API do Google, mas como meu conhecimento em JS é iniciante, as minhas tentativas foram mal sucedidas.

Aqui a div que contém meu vídeo

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 wow animated rotateIn" data-wow-duration="2s" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 50%;">
        <iframe width="100%" height="423" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1lcKDZ-RJb0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

e aqui a `div` que deve ser exibida após os 2 minutos que o vídeo foi iniciado

```
 <section class="conteudo-delay" style="display: none;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 text-center" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 50%;">
                    <a href="#">
                        <button class="mt-3 btn_compra">
                            ATUALIZE SEU PEDIDO AGORA MESMO!
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia usar esta [API do iframe do youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#IFrame_Player_API). Basicamente o que você precisa fazer para resolver seu problema (eu espero), e adicionar um script para importar esta API. Insira ela via tag:

```html
<script
   data-js="yt_api"
   src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api"
></script>
```

Na sua `div` que contém o iframe, coloque um atributo `id="ytplayer"` que vou usar para manipular via JavaScript, desta forma:

```html
<div class="row">
  <!-- este id aqui -->
  <div
    id="ytplayer" 
    class="col-sm-7 wow animated rotateIn"
    data-wow-duration="2s"
    style="margin: 0 auto; width: 50%"
  >
    <iframe
      id="player"
      width="100%"
      height="423"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1lcKDZ-RJb0"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
      allowfullscreen
    ></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Agora vem a manipulação via JavaScript. Vamos iniciar o objeto da API do youtube com a funcao `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady`:

```js
<script>
  let player;

  const conteudoDelay = document.getElementsByClassName(
    'conteudo-delay',
  )[0];

  // 1. ytplayer code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#IFrame_Player_API
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '1lcKDZ-RJb0',
    });
  }

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(Math.ceil(player.playerInfo.currentTime));

    if (Math.ceil(player.playerInfo.currentTime) >= 5) {
      conteudoDelay.setAttribute('style', 'display: block'); // agora o section vai aparecer
      clearInterval(interval); // encerra execucao do interval
    }
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Onde:

- `videoId` id do video do iframe. No seu caso `'1lcKDZ-RJb0'`.
- `conteudoDelay` e a section que iremos alterar o `display: none` para `display: block` depois de 5 segundos. Adotei 5 segundos apenas para facilitar o teste.
- Esse script `interval` server para atualizar a cada segundo (`1000` ms) e verificar o tempo decorrido do player, atraves do `player.playerInfo.currentTime`. Faremos um `if` para verificar, neste exemplo de teste, se o tempo do player for igual ou maior que 5 segundos.
- `conteudoDelay.setAttribute('style', 'display: block');` iremos exibir a section depois de 5 segundos

Codigo completo

```html
<div class="row">
  <!-- este id aqui -->
  <div
    id="ytplayer"
    class="col-sm-7 wow animated rotateIn"
    data-wow-duration="2s"
    style="margin: 0 auto; width: 50%"
  >
    <iframe
      id="player"
      width="100%"
      height="423"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1lcKDZ-RJb0"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
      allowfullscreen
    ></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="conteudo-delay" style="display: none">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-center" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 50%">
      <a href="#">
        <button class="mt-3 btn_compra">
          ATUALIZE SEU PEDIDO AGORA MESMO!
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script
  data-js="yt_api"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api"
></script>

<script>
  let player;

  const conteudoDelay = document.getElementsByClassName(
    'conteudo-delay',
  )[0];

  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '1lcKDZ-RJb0',
    });
  }

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(Math.ceil(player.playerInfo.currentTime));

    if (Math.ceil(player.playerInfo.currentTime) >= 5) {
      conteudoDelay.setAttribute('style', 'display: block'); // agora o section vai aparecer
      clearInterval(interval); // encerra execucao do interval
    }
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Teste esse codigo e veja se resolve o seu problema.

*Obviamente o codigo pode ser refatorado e melhorado. O id do video pode ser adquirido de forma dinamica tambem, mas nesse caso assumo que voce vai definir manualmente o id do video.*

Comment: muito obrigado, hoje eu vou testar tudo o que vc me passou, mais pelo que eu vi creio que vai dá certo sim, e sendo assim depois dos testes aceitarei sua resposta... Muita obrigada mesmo brother!!

Comment: Perfeito, muito bom mesmo, testei aqui e funcionou corretamente @CmteCardeal

Comment: @WPfan certo amigo! Estamos aqui pra ajudar :D

Comment: Pessoal agora usando esse metódo ai ta dando vídeo indisponível, sabem me dizer se atualizou alguma coisa?